# Can i get reference to the method toLowerCase in javascript without writing a wrapper on top of it?

Tags: javascript

I need a function that accepts a string as a parameter and converts it into lowercase in JS.

I could achieve this by writing a wrapper on top of `toLowerCase` like this

```
makeLowerCase(stringText){
 return stringText.toLowerCase();
}
```

But I was wondering if there is way to get the reference of the `toLowerCase` method itself like below so that I can avoid writing a wrapper.

```
toLowerFn = String.prototype.toLowerCase
toLowerFn('AAA') // throws error - Uncaught TypeError: String.prototype.toLowerCase called on null or undefined
```

I know in python we can get the reference of lower() function by using `str.lower` and passing to any place.

Any idea if the same can be done in JS?

Comment: Why would you need to do so instead of calling the `variable.toLowerCase()` or a function that does this ? Makes no sense at all... you do not use Javascript like this... this is not python... You are adding complexity...

Comment: @matiaslauriti it's possible that OP wants to pass this as a function reference somewhere, e.g., `arr.map(toLower)` which would be proper usage in JS. Unfortunately, `toLowerCase` is a method, which makes it quite annoying to pass as a reference.

Comment: Well, I never saw this, it seems complex for no reason, just call `variable.toLowerCase()`, no need to do complex stuff because they come from other languages...

Comment: @matiaslauriti in this case, it's JS that's more complex than it needs to be. There are proposals that aim to alleviate method binding issues. Right now, we don't have anything, unfortunately. And it *is* unfortunate, as passing function references around is at the core of JS - `str.split("").map(Number)` for example, or `arr.filter(Boolean)` are idiomatic JS code. As would be `total = shoppingBasketArr.map(getPrice).map(addShipping).reduce(sum)`. Yet we cannot do that easily with method references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it if you [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the [`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/call) with [`String#toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) as the `this` context:

```js
const str = "HELLO";

const toLower = Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.toLowerCase);

console.log(toLower(str));
```

But I would not recommend it as it looks weird and confusing. I would just write a wrapper:

```js
const str = "HELLO";

const toLower = s => s.toLowerCase();

console.log(toLower(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const foo = 'FOO';
console.log(foo.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: How does this *reference* `toLowerCase`?